# What are the best resources for learning about foraging?

Tags: food, foraging

Having recently moved the country (North Wilts, UK) I am really excited by the idea of getting out into the land and foraging for food and to brew with, but I have no idea where to start.

I don't know what to expect, how to spot it, when is best to look or if there are any legal issues. I am looking for resources on how where to start. They could be videos, books, ebooks, courses (so longs as I can reasonably attend), anything that can fill my knowledge gaps in time for the seasons to changes.

Answer (score 13):

Foraging is **NOT** looking at a plant and deciding if it's edible, nor is it looking in a book at a plant and then going looking for that plant. It's not possible to learn all the plants and it's not possible that all the plants will be in the area you forage.

Foraging is about confidently identifying *some* edible plants.

The two main components of this process are slow and steady learning coupled with an understanding of habitat and how plants and fungi feature and interact there throughout the seasons.

I recommend not buying field guides initially. Books are good for reference, but overwhelming in the early learning phase.

Set realistic goals based on the amount of time you spend outdoors.

Try something like this: http://blog.artandscienceofsurvival.com/p/free-wild-food-natural-resources-course.html

When you get a bit more confidence, take yourself on a Fungi Foray, they are always good fun.

Watch out for Wild Food courses, especially those that lay claim to you "learning 30 plants". Nobody learns 30 anything in a couple of hours, let alone remember it a few months later.

Get involved with your local Bushcraft community, they are always good for knowledge sharing. Try some of the groups on Face book like Wild Food (https://www.facebook.com/groups/189368870195/).

Good luck, take it steady and have fun.

Steve (pro survival and wild food instructor) Marvell

Comment: Just to add to the above advise. There may be quite a few groups out there that help with this. I belong to one in my area that's on the meetup website. Try googling to find one in your area.

Comment: You can also find them on sites like bushcraftuk or naturalbushcraft